# How to add an 'arrow' to the tooltip using the nvd3 tooltip

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, nvd3.js

Is there any way I can add an arrow next to the nv.tooltip hover like the way the bootstrap has??

Eg: Bootstrap tooltip/popover

[image]

nvd3 tooltip:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.nvtooltip:before` and make a triangle using CSS. [Check here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

You can check demo [here](http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#chartMarkup). Add the below styles in the CSS tab.

```
 .nvtooltip:before { 
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
    border-right: 12px solid #d1d1d1; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left: -12px;
 }
```